# Python function struggles

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm practising a bit with functions.
Now I've got the following code:

```
def BTWcalculator():

    price = input("What is the products price?")
    btw = input("Please enter a valid BTW-class: 1 = 6%, 2 = 19%")
    if btw == 1:
        return price * 1.06
    elif btw == 2:
        return price * 1.19
    else:
        BTWcalculator()


BTWcalculator()
```

However, it's not working. I'm sure is something stupid I'm missing but I just can't find my mistake.. It would be great if someone could help me.

I'm using Python 3.3.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the code as is, or does it actually have indentation? As in is `price ...` indented? Also, what error are you getting in particular?

Comment: You're using Python3.x, whose `input` returns a string - you will need to convert that to an integer first to compare against integers in your `if` statements.... `btw = int(...)`... and you probably want a float for your price... eg: `price = float(...)` etc...

Comment: Why do you mean by "it's not working". Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: This is how the code is, just copied it. And of course I should have mentioned the error :x Stupid of me. But I think Jon already solved my problem. The problem is that the function will always go to 'else', even when you typed 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cast the input to the respective type you want (using Python 3.3), because `input` returns a string. And in the `else` clause you must return the value of `BTWcalculator()` or it won't be stored nor printed.

**Code:**

```
def BTWcalculator():

    price = float(input("What is the products price?: "))
    btw = input("Please enter a valid BTW-class: 1 = 6%, 2 = 19%: ")
    if btw == "1":
        return price * 1.06
    elif btw == "2":
        return price * 1.19
    else:
        return BTWcalculator()
```

And to test it:

```
print BTWcalculator()
```

**Output:**

```
What is the products price?: 10
Please enter a valid BTW-class: 1 = 6%, 2 = 19%: 3
What is the products price?: 10
Please enter a valid BTW-class: 1 = 6%, 2 = 19%: 1
10.6
```